# Javascript - how to close current browser tab clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I want to create a button on my website that would close the current browser tab. Searching on stack overflow I got a solution but it isn't working.

This JavaScript code is:

```
function close_window(){
  if (confirm("Are you sure to close window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

HTML code is:

```
<button onclick="close_window();"> Close! </button>
```

So, How can I do this using jQuery or JavaScript for all browser?

Answer (score 0):

windows.close will work when you open the window..

Some example:

```
var tab;
$('#click').click(function() {
  tab = window.open("blackie.html", "something", "width=650,height=50");
});

$('#close').click(function() {
  tab.close();
});
```

.close() will only work when you open, you also need to tell let Js/jQ know what to close:

```
somethingThatYouDidOpen.close();
```

Comment: Actually I need to close my current window without creating new window using `window.open()`. Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not. You can create a overlayer or modal to show content and close it or direct to another page.. but browser denied to close when not did open by script.